# How to read a click event from any current existing website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

Apologies for any mistake, am completely new to node.js. I am trying to get a button click event from the existing website. For example if I click login button in a [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) website I need to get that event and print button clicked in my terminal. I tried puppeteer, cheerio and axios, all these has the option to automate a click but not to read a click event. Can somebody help me with it or advice me an alternate possible approach to get it done.

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126167/how-to-read-a-click-event-from-any-current-existing-website/68126333#68126333', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  
  const element = window.document.getElementById("upvoteBtn")
element.onclick = function() {
 console.log("Upvoted!")
}

})();
```

[Getting this error for the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76h1c.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "existing website"?  If you are viewing www.xyz.com in a browser so that you, as a human, can click a button, then your code isn't running.  You can't get events.  What are you picturing?

Comment: @TimRoberts What am trying to do is when am browsing through a website and if I make a click in any of the button in the website I need to read the click with the id of the button or class name through the code and print in the terminal that button clicked.

Answer (score 1):

With puppeteer, you have 2 different scopes: Node.js scope and browser scope. Variables from one scope are not defined in other one. Here is a way to communicate between these scopes and to achieve your goal:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://example.org/');

  await page.exposeFunction('logClickedElement', (name) => {
    console.log(`Clicked element: ${name}.`);
  });

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      window.logClickedElement(event.target.tagName);
    });
  });
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ID of the button you could get the element then assign a function to it's onclick property. Although this may overwrite the existing functionality.

Say the upvote button had an ID of `upvoteBtn` (which you can give it in the elements panel).

[image: button element]

```
const element = window.document.getElementById("upvoteBtn")
element.onclick = function() {
 console.log("Upvoted!")
}
```

In the case of SO, the button retains its expected functionality and also prints to the console.

Comment: I tried the below given code and getting the error, window is not defined.

Comment: const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126167/how-to-read-a-click-event-from-any-current-existing-website/68126333#68126333', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  
  const element = window.document.getElementById("upvoteBtn")
element.onclick = function() {
 console.log("Upvoted!")
}

})();